# How to access httpcontext.current or session values in thread in asp .net

Tags: asp.net

I have a method , it takes some time like 4 minutes , for that i want show a text in the page about completion of method like for  1 min, 2 min, 3 min and some data i want to store session and that i want to access in ajax timer and want to show the status of the method like completion state for make user to understand how much the method completed.
Thanks

Comment: you need to look into threading. your .net page will lock the request until the method is complete. by using threading you can have more then one thing going on at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Use the HeartBeat design pattern.
Your javascript will call a custom HTTP handler thru Ajax calls (every x seconds), and that handler will return status information to the javascript using JSON data. Next, you will update your progress control according to that data.